# What this warning means `Required tables DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO,DBMSHP_PARENT_CHILD_INFO,DBMSHP_RUNS missing`

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Recently we upgraded from oracle 12c to 19c. Now I'm testing if everything works fine, but I  came acrross to some functions that have under the `profiles` in the `SQL DEVELOPER` this warning

```
Required tables DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO,DBMSHP_PARENT_CHILD_INFO,DBMSHP_RUNS missing
```

When I at looked at the other instance that currently is using oracle 12c - I see the same warning.

I havent worked on this data for that long and I'm not sure what is for what yet.
I was wondering if there are some explanations regarding this warning.

Any help? I'm just trying to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the tables required to use the PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler are missing.

[image]

I talk about this feature in SQL Developer [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/02/sql-developer-the-pl-sql-hierarchical-profiler/)

If you're not using the feature, it's not a problem. If you want to use the feature, then SQL Developer will help you create the objects via the GUI when you go to use the Profiler on a PL/SQL code editor.